# Transparency in CGContext

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-graphics

I'm trying to set a transparent background for a CGContext but keep getting :

```
CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0
```

Here's what I've got. If I switch kCGImageAlphaLast to kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst it works but the alpha channel is completely ignored. I'm very new to this color & context stuff - any ideas?

```
-(BOOL) initContext:(CGSize)size {
int bitmapByteCount;
int bitmapBytesPerRow;

bitmapBytesPerRow = (size.width * 4);
bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height);

cacheBitmap = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
if (cacheBitmap == NULL){
    return NO;
}

cacheContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, size.width, size.height, 8, bitmapBytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaLast);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(cacheContext, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0f, 0.5);
CGContextFillRect(cacheContext, self.bounds);

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CGBitmapContext` supports only certain possible pixel formats.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB) You probably want `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`.

(Here's an [explanation of premultiplied alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing).)

Also note:

- There is no need to malloc `cacheBitmap`. Since you are passing in `NULL` as the first argument to `CGBitmapContextCreate`, the bitmap context will do its own allocation.
- Depending on your code, `self.bounds` may not be the correct rectangle to fill. It would be safer to use `CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, size.width, size.height)`.