# Black view when overriding drawRect:

Tags: ios, cgcontext

So I am following a [simple tutorial](http://www.effectiveui.com/blog/2011/12/02/how-to-build-a-simple-painting-app-for-ios/) to enable the user to draw on the view and I have got the code working. But I'd like to add a background image to the view, so the user is drawing on that image.

The issue I'm having is that the background of my `PaintView` is always black, but there are non-black views behind the `PaintView`.

I think the issue is that `CGImageRef cacheImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cacheContext);` creates a black background when I want it to create a transparent background.

So now the question is, how can I solve this so that the background of my `PaintView` is transparent (or the image I get from `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`, depending on what exactly is the issue).

The code suggested in the tutorial:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGImageRef cacheImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cacheContext);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, cacheImage);
    CGImageRelease(cacheImage);
}
```

The code I use to draw the image:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if(_snapshot != nil) {
        [_snapshot drawInRect:rect];
    }
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGImageRef cacheImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(cacheContext);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, cacheImage);
    CGImageRelease(cacheImage);
}
```

Where `_snapshot` is the `UIImage` I want to display.

My next thought is that when I create the cacheContext, I initialise it with a black background, which should be transparent. Any ideas how to do this?

EDIT: I have removed everything involving the `CGContext` from `drawRect`(leaving only the drawing of my image), which works to draw the image, but including the CGContext calls, this renders as black.

<sup>PS: I am currently using Xamarin, but I have asked in Objective-C because Xamarin renames a lot of things related to CGContexts. I can read C#, Objective-C and Swift, so you can answer in any language.</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552085/transparency-in-cgcontext) solved my problem:

> [`CGBitmapContext` supports only certain possible pixel formats.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB) You probably want `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`.